# How to fill spaces left between curved roads

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image: Text](https://stackoverflo[![enter image description here]

I made roads with beveling curve in the geometry section. It works perfect for straight lines but whenever the road is curved it breaks up int smaller straight roads which do not join from edge to edge.

I want it to be a perfect curved road. Help!

Comment: multiple splines?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your curve options? I'm not really clear on how you set it up. Did you use an array modifier?

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a road doing the following and it worked fine.

Create a curve for your road. Create a plane and in edit mode hit X and then “only faces”. Next convert the plane to a curve.

Finally, go into the curve for the road and set the bevel object to a the Plane curve.

This worked for me, so I hope it helps!